# How to achieve a recursive deftype

Tags: data-structures, clojure, type-hinting, deftype

I'm curious as to how to do a Clojure deftype that contains a reference to itself, e.g.

```
  (deftype BinaryTree [^BinaryTree left ^BinaryTree right])
```

This doesn't work... however I see no intrinsic reason why it shouldn't be possible since the underlying Java class is perfectly capable of referring to itself.

What am I doing wrong here?

Mike.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently ^Class hints on fields (in opposition to ^primitive hints) are discarded, so there's no gain in trying to put them. This may change in the future.

However auto reference in a type definition (eg in method bodies, not in fields) somewhat works but the implementation is a bit of a hack. There's little incentive to fix auto-reference in the current java compiler given the promise of the rewrite of the compiler in Clojure.

Comment: thanks - very helpful explanation (though also annoying as I'd really like to use some recursive references!)